# Есть ли смысл писать мета тег c content="IE=edge,chrome=1" при использовании css переменных?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

В проекте используется css переменные, а они не поддерживаются в IE 11 и ниже (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)
Есть ли смысл в том чтобы писать это `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`?
Если да, то какой?

Comment: а откуда взята эта строчка?

Comment: В зависимости от того как вёрстка выглядит без css-переменных. Если там месиво - смысла нет, если слетают некоторые цвета, режим совместимости можно оставить.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров, впринципе да, спасибо